# creating TCPClient giving me exception

Tags: c#, sockets, exception, tcpclient

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(Dns.GetHostAddresses("localhost")[0],8080);
        List<TcpClient> TCPs = new List<TcpClient>();
        int i = 1;
            while (true) {
                Console.Write(i + " ");
                /* the exception's row */ TCPs.Add(new TcpClient(ip));
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

giving me this exception:

```
 An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

Comment: The first or the second try?

Comment: Have you checked that port is not opened already? Please take a look a [this Microsoft KB article](http://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.1.2600.2180&EvtID=4226&EvtSrc=Tcpip&LCID).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot bind to the same port more than once. Because of your `while(true)` loop, you create a new `TcpClient` over and over again. The first one you create will grab port 8080 and the second one fails with this exception.

from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bsb3c8f.aspx):

> Before you call this constructor, you must create an IPEndPoint using the IP address and port number from which you intend to send and receive data.

Usually there is no need to set a port when creating a client.

Comment: hey? What do I need to do?

Comment: I don't know. What do you want to achieve? Your code as it stands tries to create stuff that is not possible.